# How do I set a windows environment variable inside a git commit message?

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, environment-variables, devops

I'm working on a Azure Devops release task on a azure Windows machine in which I do the following:

- Execute some .sql files against a database
- Run a PowerShell script to perform some file moving/writing/copying on the repository
- Run a PowerShell script to perform a `git add .` and `a git commit` command

In the last job, I'm trying to create a commit message similar to:
"Automatic commit: perform some actions from build number:   ${RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__MYREPO_BUILDNUMBER}"
with no success at all.

How do I set RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__MYREPO_BUILDNUMBER azure devops environment variable value in a commit message executed by a PowerShell script?

Comment: Do you mean `$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__MYREPO_BUILDNUMBER = "Some value"?`

Comment: I'm dumb, please respond this and get some stack overflow points

Comment: Done. I wasn't sure if your question was "How do I set an environment variable in PowerShell?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an environment variable in PowerShell using the `env:` drive, as in:

```
$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__MYREPO_BUILDNUMBER = "Some value"
```

or:

```
Set-Item env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__MYREPO_BUILDNUMBER "Some value"
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, I ended up doing something like this:


>$build_number = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER

>git commit -m "Automatic commit on date: $date | Sent applied migration to history folder for release triggered by build number: $build_number"

My repo has a name in format "name-name", and powershell dind't like that, so I managed to get my info from BUILD_BUILDNUMBER environment name instead of RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__MYREPO_BUILDNUMBER